# Xdebug doesn't work on Chrome (IDE : VSCode)

Tags: php, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I need help.. I try to configure xDebug on my localhost environment, that's work fine if I run the `index.php` from the terminal (`php index.php`) but when I call this file from Chrome. It don't stop at my  my break-point...

For this project, I need to be on PHP@7.2. I use VSCode as IDE. XDebug v3.1.5 is installed. I also installed the XDebug Helper extension on Chrome.

VSCODE preference > PHP Debug > Ide Key = `vsc`

XDebug Helper options > Ide Key = `vsc`

There is my ext-xdebug.ini file :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=vsc
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

edit : adding this parameters to my ini file

```
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level=10
```

There is my launch.json :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
        },
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your advice and help.

Comment: What does Xdebug's log say? If you don't have one, set `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10` (and restart your webserver/PHP-FPM if needed).

Comment: Last friday I made several restart of the httpd services (`brew services restart httpd`). But no changes with xdebug.
Yesterday, after a little break and after adding `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10` to my .ini file, x-debug works fine! 
(I tried to remove the new xdebug parameters, and still work. Idk that's dark magic! ) 
Thanks for your help!